# MediaElement.js problems in Wordpress 3.3.2

Tags: wordpress, video, mediaelement.js

I can't seem to get my videos to load using MediaElement.js since upgrading to wordpress 3.3.2

The pages from my website with the videos on are [here](http://www.strelitziamusic.co.uk/wedding-string-quartet/) and [here](http://www.strelitziamusic.co.uk/string-quartet-promotional-video/)

When you click on play it attempts to load but doesn't actually do it. The files do exist.

Any one else with similar problems since updating?

Audio elsewhere on the site works fine.

Comment: http://www.strelitziamusic.co.uk/wedding-string-quartet/ does not work in Win7/IE; the player loads & I see the progress bar working, but nothing else happens.  I downloaded the .MP4 file, & it will not run in VLC2.0; broken file?

Comment: Your correct! Sorry for that and thanks for pointing it out. It appears that using FileZilla seemed to have corrupted the files. Just tried uploading the same file using it and then using the standard wordpress uploader and the FileZilla one was corrupted. Not sure why but many thanks.

Comment: So your issue is solved then?  Just a bad FileZilla upload?  I wonder if those tools have a "checksum" function...